# matlab, measure of spatial spread

Tags: matlab, spatial, spread

Having data points in a 3D neighbourhood (see attached picture), I would like to define a measure of spatial spread to accept or reject the data set as a candidate for further analysis. One measure could be how many of the cells in the 3D subvolume (the bounding box) are occupied by the neighbourhood. Another would be how the data stretches along each of the axis. Are there other and better criteria for measuring the spatial spread ?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: I am sorry. I wasn't aware. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @user1641496 What is the nature of your data? Is it a 3-D matrix with real values?

Comment: Yes. I start with a large volume, throw away all the cells in the volume that are less than some value (set to zero) and then do a segmentation (matlab's regionprops). I am left with a few segments, each defining a neighbourhood. I need to chose the most likely candidate: which segment contains the maximum value, which spreads over larger area, how concentrated  each segment is and so on. The one that fulfils most of the above is the most likely candidate. Thanks

Comment: @user1641496 so basically an acceptable solution would be one that analyses a segment and returns true/false, or some kind of a value on a scale (say between 1 and 10)?

Comment: yes, rather the second option, that is, each segment gets a score and the highest scoring one is picked. Or maybe all of them rejected. Much weight should be given to how well concentrated the segment/region is. If the segment is too scattered(too many holes inside), then it is probably not a good candidate.

Comment: Have you looked at `convhull` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html I believe it should get you pointed in the right direction